# .NET Attributes versus Java Annotations: Which Came First?

Tags: .net, jakarta-ee

I'm a .NET developer learning Java EE.  These two concepts seem to serve the same exact purposes in either system.

So which framework gets credit for inventing them?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[.NET metadata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_metadata) was, *I believe*, introduced in [.NET 1.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#.NET_Framework_1.1) which was released 3 April 2003 (it appears to be already in before that?). The [Java annotations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_annotation) were proposed as [JSR-175](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=175) on 19 March 2002 which was approved on 30 September 2004 and became part of [Java SE 5.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#J2SE_5.0_.28September_30.2C_2004.29) which was released the same day.

It's unclear when exactly .NET metadata was proposed, but when it comes to the first release, .NET wins.

Comment: Java annotations draw their inspiration from XDoclet, which is a more general version of EJBDoclet (annotations in documenting comments). First release: june 2001. (http://xdoclet.sourceforge.net/olddocs/CHANGES.txt)

Answer (score 16):

Attributes have been part of the CLR since its inception. I have an old prerelease spec of C# printed out from November 1999 that describes them, but the earliest reference I can find is the [C# 1.0 spec from 2001](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-WITHDRAWN/ECMA-334,%201st%20edition,%20December%202001.pdf). This was clearly several years before the feature was added to Java.

EDIT: The book, [C# Programming with the Public Beta](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1861004877), was published in 2000 and mentions attributes.

Comment: +1 for actual resources. That's early btw!

Answer (score 8):

I believe they came first with .NET; Java 5 followed.

> Java has unfortunately been behind the
>   curve on language improvents despite
>   the fact it was the language C# was
>   modeled after.

Pierreten's comment is correct, but I think there are several factors that explain it:

1. Java has a longer legacy than .NET,
   and maintaining backward
   compatibility is a high priority
2. Java community process takes longer to build consensus; Microsoft doesn't need any such consensus if it believes a feature is needed.
3. Sun's financial decline and eventual purchase by Oracle meant fewer resources were available to devote to Java.
4. Sun has lost the minds that drove Java forward at its height (e.g., Bill Joy, James Gosling).  Anders Hejlsberg and Eric Lippert are still with Microsoft.

(Eric Lippert [left Microsoft in Jan 2013](http://ericlippert.com/about-eric-lippert/) to join Coverity.)

Comment: Java has unfortunately been behind the curve on language improvents despite the fact it was the language C# was modeled after

Comment: Thanks for background info duffymo; I figured there would be a fair amount of politics at play

Comment: Eric Lippert has left MS by now.

Comment: Looks like you're right - he left Microsoft to join Coverity just three months ago, in Jan 2013.  http://ericlippert.com/about-eric-lippert/