# Using Annotations in dotnet

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, annotations, custom-attributes

I've never used C# attributes, but understand that they are the rough equivalent of Java annotations.

If I proceed with the port using attributes to replace annotations, what do I need to know? What's going to be the same? Different? What's going to bite me?

As for as my research i found that

> C# uses the **ConditionalAttribute** attribute that is driven from compile time symbols

i just want to know whether can we write annotation on our own and
which versions of dotnet supports it?

It is appreciated that if i got any samples or documents to read

Waiting for your valuable response and comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can write your own attributes - you just inherit from `Attribute`, i.e.

```
public class FooAttribute : Attribute {
    public int Bar {get;set;}
}
```

then you can attach that:

```
[Foo(Bar=12)]
public int X {get;set;}
```

(see also `AttributeUsageAttribute` if you want to limit what it can be applied to - for example to classes, fields, interfaces, etc)

Note that while some attributes (`ConditionalAttribute`, `ObsoleteAttribute`, etc) have meaning to the compiler, you **cannot** write your own compile-time features with attributes, except via 3rd-party tools such as PostSharp. What you *can* do is check for the attribute at runtime via reflection (in particular, `Attribute.GetCustomAttribute[s]`), and react accordingly with code. Most attributes are used in this way by reflection.

```
foreach(var prop in type.GetProperties()) {
    var foo = (FooAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(
                        prop, typeof(FooAttribute));
    if(foo != null) {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} has Foo.Bar: {1}", prop.Name, foo.Bar);
    }
}
```

All versions of .NET support attributes, although in some of the limited frameworks you might find some of the BCL attributes are missing if not required. For example, `DataContractAttribute` doesn't exist on a platform that doesn't support WCF via `DataContractSerializer`.

Comment: Thanks for posting can you provide me some links that refer the program using annotations ?

Comment: @Gowthammanju you mean consuming them? example added - does that do what you mean?

Comment: Thanks is it possible to go to some specific class using annotations before entering the current class in c#.net

Comment: @Gowthammanju you would have to be more specific, but: if you mean "can I make this attribute execute code automatically when this type / property / etc is invoked", then no, not with regular .NET; however, "AOP" tools like PostSharp (mentioned above) *do* allow that type of usage. Without tools like PostSharp, attributes are *metadata* - not automatic code injection points. I *could*, for example, add a method to `FooAttribute`, but I would need to obtain the `FooAttribute` as shown in order to execute it explicitly.

Comment: ya thanks for your support @Marc Gravell i already used postsharp to do it but i just want to know whether we can implement with out any third party tool

Comment: @Gowthammanju no there isn't. If you knew about PostSharp, I'm rather confused as to what you *didn't* know about attributes, but... whatever.

Answer (score 1):

.NET attributes and Java annotations serve similar purposes.

Attributes in .NET are supported in all versions starting from v1.1.

More details about some history: [.NET Attributes versus Java Annotations: Which Came First?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807533/net-attributes-versus-java-annotations-which-came-first)

And yes, you can write your own attributes in .NET. (Of course, you'll have to process them in your own code - or nothing will happen (unless you subclass one of the existing attributes to modify their behaviour).